# iex- How to run an elixir project from outside the app folder

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

I have some situation,
in which i need to run an elixir project, from outside the project file.
i.e. i have a folder `code/example-app` that contains the app (with the `mix.exs` and all the rest)
and i would like to run that app from `code`,
without `cd`-ing into `example-app`.
Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the location of the `mix.exs` file using the `MIX_EXS` environment variable.

```
MIX_EXS=./code/example-app/mix.exs mix deps.get
```

You can read more about the environment variables that affect mix in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#module-environment-variables).

Just note that if you try to execute a task that is defined inside of the project or one of its dependencies, it will not work.